# Change Emacs 24 theme depending on connected monitors

Tags: emacs, dbus

I'm using Emacs 24 on my Ubuntu Linux running laptop, which is usually connected to a very nice external monitor, where I like one color theme (using deftheme). But when I'm on the road, I like another deftheme.

How can I make Emacs listen to monitor connection events, and set the theme accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is an easy way to react on changes to the display configuration.  On Linux, you may be lucky to find a DBus service that signals such changes, which you can react upon by means of the [Emacs D-Bus library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/dbus/index.html), but on OS X and Windows I doubt that there is such a simple way.

You may be better off with a simple key binding that toggles between your two favorite themes:

```
(defvar my-current-theme nil
  "The last used theme.")

(defun my-toggle-themes ()
  "Toggle between my favorite themes."
  (let ((new-theme (if (eq my-current-theme 'solarized-light)
                       'zenburn 'solarized-light)))
    (load-theme new-theme :no-confirm)
    (setq my-current-theme new-theme)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c t") #'my-toggle-themes)
```